# WPF DataContext. Taking from another class

Tags: wpf, datacontext

having general DataContext taken from class **SearchByID** there's a need to take a separate DataContext from another class, say, **testClass**.

**XAML example:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <model:SearchById />
 </Window.DataContext>

<Grid>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}">
<Texblock.DataContext>
<model: testClass/>
</TextBlock.DataContext>
</TextBlock>


</Grid>
```

There are no fails, IntelliSens sees all the Properties.
But the TextBlock is blank.

any ideas please.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense to assign a testClass instance to the DataContext of a TextBlock, only to show its Description property, which could only be initialized once in the testClass instance. You may perhaps better bind directly to a static property. It is unclear what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea, is the `Description` a property or a field?

A [`Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) will work:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public TestClass()
    {
        Description = "Test";
    }
}
```

A [`field`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) won't:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Description;
    public TestClass()
    {
        Description = "Test";
    }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
           Background="Yellow" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.DataContext>
        <local:TestClass />
    </TextBlock.DataContext>
</TextBlock>
```

Result:
[image: the word test on a white background highlighted yellow]

Comment: the "Description" is a property of class  testClass.

Comment: You have mentioned above "fields". If "Description" is a field. Won't it work. Or?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. A field (the second example) won't work.

Comment: I have understood what you meant. A question: why so? What a reason?

Comment: @Bolt data binding works with public properties only. If Description is one, and it is initialized appropriately, your code should work. You would have to provide more details in your question, i.e. show the declaration and initialization of the property.